# compare metadata of parquet file using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, schema, metadata, parquet

I am using pyspark and have a situation where I need to compare metadata of 2 parquet files.

Example:-

Parquet 1 Schema is :
1, ID, string
2, address string
3, Date, date

Parquet 2 Schema is :
1, ID, string
2, Date, date
3, address string

This should show me a difference, as col 2 moved to col 3 in parquet 2.

Thanks,
VK

Answer (score 0):

In Spark there isn't a native command to do the comparison of the headers. A  solution to your problem could be the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.read.parquet('path/to/file1.parquet', header='true')
df2= spark.read.parquet('path/to/file2.parquet', header='true')

df1_headers = df1.columns
df2_headers = df2.columns

# Now in Python you could compare the lists with the headers
# You don't need Spark to compare simple headers :-)
```

Comment: Thanks, header = True does not work, but we can take columns into a list. now the issue is I need to compare sequentially, if order also changed that should be reported as well.. can you suggest how can we achieve this

Comment: I just added this and it gives the desired result

Comment: for i in range(len(df1_headers)):
  
  a=(diff(df2_headers[i],df1_headers[i]))
  if a:
    print(df1_headers[i],df2_headers[i])

Comment: @Vishvanath yes in header there was a typo, but I fix it. The comparison which you want is not relevant with Spark but is a Python question, because you compare lists. You use Spark only to create the columns then it's a Python question. So, you can check now my corrected answer, and if it works, accept the answer and create a new one with the comparison (without Spark tags). Are we ok?